# Parameterise variables in sitespeed.io scripting

Tags: performance-testing, client-side-scripting

I am working to create client side scripting usins sitespeed.io.

Scenario : seach different group item which will have different page/frame as response.

code sample:

```
export default async function (context, commands) {
  await commands.measure.start('Navigate to page');
  await commands.addText.byClass('seachgroup','00000000124');
  await commands.measure.stop();
}
```

here `00000000124` is some group item id to seach which need to be parameterise.

Question : is there a way we can use any config file/ parameter file where we can mention all required group id and pass them to main script (.mjs).